# Is there a way to call a Method<T>() by defining T from an object?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to call a generic method I've created called `LoadItems<T>()`. This method does a bunch of operations on a `List<T>` of items it returns from the database.

The problem I have is in calling the `LoadItems<T>()` method. All I have to work with is an object. I want to resolve this object into a T so that I can call my method.

In a pseudo way of explaining:

```
object theObject = GetTheObject();
LoadItems<GetGenericType(theObject)>();
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a ton

Comment: Quite easily via reflection. Same has been asked many times here.

Comment: @leppie: but why pass up the easy rep points?

Comment: @siride: Does it look like I need more rep? ;p (and there, have some)

Comment: @leppie: no, but I do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use reflection or change your design.

If you want to use reflection, the process is complicated:

```
// get the type of the object variable
var objType = theObject.GetType();

// I'm assuming that LoadItems() is a method in the current class
var selfType = GetType();

// you might need to use an overload of GetMethod() -- please read the documentation!
var methodInfo = selfType.GetMethod("LoadItems");

// this fills in the generic arguments
var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { objType });

// this calls LoadItems<T>() with T filled in; I'm assuming it's a method on this class
var results = genericMethodInfo.Invoke(this, null);
```

Note that `results` will be an `object`. If you want it to be a specific `List<>` type, you're out of luck. You don't know what the type is at compile time. You can cast it to the non-generic `IList`, or use some LINQ expression to convert it to something more useful, like this:

```
var niceResults = results.Cast<SomeBaseType>().ToList();
```

As always, read the documentation on the functions I listed above if you aren't sure what's going on.

Comment: Spot on, appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using reflection:

```
MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("LoadItems").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { theObject.GetType() });

mi.Invoke(this, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

To get types of object you would commonly use

```
typeof(GetTheObject)
```

or

```
theObject.GetType()
```

But shouldnt you be defining you function like this?

```
    public void LoadItems<T>(T obj)
    {

    }
```

And calling it like this?

```
LoadItems(theObject);
```

Comment: Not sure how this covers the question. Did you forget to finish your answer?

Comment: "And calling it like this?" -- no, that's not how the OP is calling it. If that were true, this would be ultra easy and the OP likely wouldn't have asked.